# Is there a way to map each CVE to a technique/tactic in the mitre ATT&CK matrix?

Tags: cve, mitre

The only 'solution' I thought of is linking a CVE to a CWE and then to a CAPEC (Method found in this link: [How to find CAPEC items related to a CVE](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/187196/how-to-find-capec-items-related-to-a-cve)) but I am unable to get from a CAPEC attack pattern to a technique/tactic in the ATT&CK matrix.

(On a side note what is the difference between CAPEC and the ATT&CK matrix? They both seem to serve the same purpose to me)

Comment: Many an unfortunate soul has be tasked over the years with doing this. Good Luck!

Comment: CVE:ATT&CK mapping would not be 1:1 rather many:many. On the difference between CAPEC and ATT&CK see [https://capec.mitre.org/about/attack_comparison.html](https://capec.mitre.org/about/attack_comparison.html)